# Set a ValidationError by Code in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I came across [Set a ValidationError by Code, by Christian Mosers](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValidationErrorByCode.html)

```
ValidationError validationError = new ValidationError(regexValidationRule, 
    textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty));

validationError.ErrorContent = "This is not a valid e-mail address";

Validation.MarkInvalid(textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty), 
    validationError);
```

How can I use this in my ViewModel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other ways to get errors out of the VM, for example by implementing [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) or by throwing exceptions in setters (the binding then needs to [validate on exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks and +1 for you answer, I was aware of the IDataErrorInfo (should've mentioned that in my question). If you get a chance could you also provide comments or some code showing how to use the technique from Christina Mosers with regards to the question?

Comment: @VoodooChild: As far as i am aware you should not have a reference to UI-elements in your VM, and the approach mentioned requires you to have a reference to the UI-element which displays your data. That being the case i do not think it is suited for this pattern.